# bgcolor for specific date

Tags: pine-script

I want to give background color for specific date.  i am trying below code in pine script version 5.

```
date = timestamp(2021, 01, 19, 09, 30)
bgcolor(date ? color.new(color.red,70) : na)
```

As date is true it paints whole chart background to red, can some one help me to contain red color to that specific date only?

i just want it paint bgcolor red only for given date i.e "2021, 01, 19, 09, 30". couldn`t find help in manual or elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay=true)

var int     myDate  = input.time(timestamp("13 Jan 2022 09:30 -0500"), 'Choose date/time')
var color   myColor = color.new(color.red,70)

bgcolor(myDate == time ? myColor : na)
```

Edit 1, in answer to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70699470/bgcolor-for-specific-date-pine-script/70699873?noredirect=1#comment124999949_70699873)

If you have several dates, you could put them into an array.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay=true)

var color   myColor = color.new(color.red,70)
var int[]   myDates = array.new_int()

if barstate.isfirst
    array.push(myDates, timestamp(2021, 12, 01, 09, 30))
    array.push(myDates, timestamp(2021, 12, 15, 09, 30))
    array.push(myDates, timestamp(2022, 01, 05, 09, 30))
    array.push(myDates, timestamp(2022, 01, 11, 09, 30))

bgcolor(array.includes(myDates, time) ? myColor : na)
```

Or a shorter version

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay=true)

var color   myColor = color.new(color.red,70)
var int[]   myDates = array.from(timestamp(2021, 12, 01, 09, 30), timestamp(2021, 12, 15, 09, 30), timestamp(2022, 01, 05, 09, 30), timestamp(2022, 01, 11, 09, 30))

bgcolor(array.includes(myDates, time) ? myColor : na)
```

Which yields

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hi, yes this works but i need to go to settings and then select date again only then it shows. Like here on 13th Jan if you add to chart it does not show you need to go to settings and select date again and it works then. I have alot of dates that i need to give bgcolor. So practically i guess this might not work in that case.

Comment: Added Edit 1 to my answer for a solution to this.